# how to display department details along with number of employees for each department?

Tags: sql

from **employee-department** schema how to get details of each ***department***(department id, department name) along with number of employees for each department.

Comment: Share the schema and query you have tried.

Comment: Without actually seeing your table structure I can only advise you `count(employees)` and group by department.

Comment: department table has (deptId,deptName), employee table has (empId,empname,deptId) here deptId in employee table is foreign key. now i want to get deptId,deptName,number of employees

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
select dept.deptId,
   deptName,
   count(emp.empid) as numb_of_emps
   from department dept inner join employee emp
   on dept.deptid = emp.deptid
   group by dept.deptid
```

Answer (score 3):

that you can take as - 
( as  Russell Dias  also have suggested )

```
select d.deptId,
       deptName,
       count(e.empid) "number of employees"
from department d, employee e
where d.deptid = e.deptid
group by d.deptid,d.deptname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not need the actual department details, but just the department name you could simplify this further like so :

```
SELECT department_name, COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees" 
FROM employees group by department;
```

Comment: this will not give that department which has no employees

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.deptno,dname,count(e.empno) "No of Emp"
from dept d, emp e 
where d.deptno = e.deptno
group by d.deptno,d.dname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT department_name,COUNT(*) FROM employees a,departments b
where a.department_id=b.department_id
group by department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.deptno, d.dname, count(e.empno) "Number of employees"
from dept d, emp e
where d.deptno = e.deptno
group by d.deptno,d.dname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN:

```
Select  e.EmployeeName,
        d.DepartmentName,
        count(d.DepId)As Total_no_of_Employees
From Department d
Inner join Employee e 
    On d.DepId = e.EmpID
Groub By DepartmentName, Total_no_of_Employees
```